# zxing - java library how to generate qrCOde

Tags: java, zxing

is there any website or document or ... to completely explain how to generate qrCode using zxing in java?
i've just found a website which just posted complete code to generate but i want a complete reference to functions.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the Jar from zxing and then you should/can begin with [this example](http://crunchify.com/java-simple-qr-code-generator-example/):